# How can I merge output of two queries on two different databases in one single view on Tableau

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

I am working with two MS-SQL databases and using a query on each database, I am able to get some data in a format which is common for both databases (i.e same column names and datatypes of field values). A brief overview of data is:

Output 1 :

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
A    1    1
A    2    1
A    1    2
```

Output 2:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
B    2    1
C    3    1
D    1    3
```

And I want below data in a single view on tableau:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
A    1    1
A    2    1
A    1    2
B    2    1
C    3    1
D    1    3
```

I have tried creating a clipboard data source, but the issue came when I tried creating calculated fields based on my previous two data sources. It only permits to have calculated field value as an aggregate value. I want the original value and not the aggregate. Help needed here!

Comment: I would do this at the database layer. But it is on the roadmap to have UNION capabilities in Tableau's data connection GUI.

Comment: @Bernardo You are absolutely right about doing this at the database layer, but unfortunately sometimes tableau developers have only read only access on the database. For the time being, the only visible solution appears to me is to export db tables into excel files and then merge them.

Comment: @MohitSharma, could you do a `union all` in a custom sql? I've had to do that in several queries against ms sql server and oracle. It avoids having to add things to the db layer.

Answer (score 0):

If the two databases are accessible by a common database user, use a `union all` to merge the two queries together into one data set. You'll need to write the sql and then create Custom SQL for the database table.

If they aren't accessible by a common database user, look into the possibility of doing linked databases so the db user can see both tables and union.

Comment: The tables I am working with are on two different servers. Hence only latter option is left with me. And sadly for that too I have to wait till DB team responds!